Why are upper and lower pitchfork lines staying red in MetaTrader 4?
I’m working on an MQL4 code for MetaTrader 4 that creates a custom Pitchfork with three lines: the central, upper, and lower lines. The central line, which is supposed to be red, works correctly. However, the upper and lower lines, which should be blue (as set in the default options), remain red. I’ve checked the default color settings in MetaTrader, which clearly show that the upper and lower lines should be blue, while the central red line is displayed correctly. Despite this, when I place the Pitchfork on the chart, all three lines appear red.
MT4 input blue and red line
MT4 all lines of pitchfork are red
I’m looking for a solution that will allow the upper and lower lines of the Pitchfork to respect the default settings and display in blue, while the central line remains red. I’ve attached the MQL4 code, hoping that someone can spot what’s causing this issue and suggest how to fix it. Ideally, I’d like the outcome to be similar to what I get on TradingView, where the upper and lower lines are blue, and the central one stays red.
TradingView pitchfork with blue and red line
Code:
#property copyright "Your Name"
#property link      "http://www.yourwebsite.com"
#property version   "1.00"
#property strict
#property indicator_chart_window

input datetime Time1 = D'2022.01.01 00:00'; // Tempo punto 1
input double   Price1 = 0;                 // Prezzo punto 1
input datetime Time2 = D'2022.01.02 00:00'; // Tempo punto 2
input double   Price2 = 0;                 // Prezzo punto 2
input datetime Time3 = D'2022.01.03 00:00'; // Tempo punto 3
input double   Price3 = 0;                 // Prezzo punto 3

input color InpUpperColor = clrBlue;    // Colore linea superiore
input color InpMiddleColor = clrRed;    // Colore linea centrale
input color InpLowerColor = clrBlue;    // Colore linea inferiore
input color InpCursorColor = clrWhite;  // Colore cursore e testo
input ENUM_LINE_STYLE InpLineStyle = STYLE_SOLID; // Stile linee
input int InpLineWidth = 1;             // Spessore linee
input int InpProximity = 10;            // Prossimità per snap (in pixel)

bool drawing = true;
int point_count = 0;
datetime time1, time2, time3;
double price1, price2, price3;

string cursor_line = "CursorLine";
string price_text = "PriceText";
string time_text = "TimeText";
string pitchfork_name = "Pitchfork";

int OnInit()
{
   EventSetTimer(1);
   ChartSetInteger(0, CHART_EVENT_MOUSE_MOVE, true);
   
   if(Time1 != D'2022.01.01 00:00' && Price1 != 0 &&
      Time2 != D'2022.01.02 00:00' && Price2 != 0 &&
      Time3 != D'2022.01.03 00:00' && Price3 != 0)
   {
      time1 = Time1; price1 = Price1;
      time2 = Time2; price2 = Price2;
      time3 = Time3; price3 = Price3;
      DrawPitchfork();
      drawing = false;
   }
   
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}

void OnDeinit(const int reason)
{
   EventKillTimer();
   ObjectDelete(0, pitchfork_name);
   ObjectDelete(0, cursor_line);
   ObjectDelete(0, price_text);
   ObjectDelete(0, time_text);
}

int OnCalculate(const int rates_total, const int prev_calculated, const datetime &time[],
                const double &open[], const double &high[], const double &low[],
                const double &close[], const long &tick_volume[], const long &volume[],
                const int &spread[])
{
   return(rates_total);
}

void OnChartEvent(const int id, const long &lparam, const double &dparam, const string &sparam)
{
   if(id == CHARTEVENT_CLICK && drawing)
   {
      datetime clicked_time;
      double clicked_price;
      int window;
      
      if(ChartXYToTimePrice(0, (int)lparam, (int)dparam, window, clicked_time, clicked_price))
      {
         int bar = iBarShift(NULL, 0, clicked_time);
         datetime bar_time = iTime(NULL, 0, bar);
         double bar_open = iOpen(NULL, 0, bar);
         double bar_high = iHigh(NULL, 0, bar);
         double bar_low = iLow(NULL, 0, bar);
         double bar_close = iClose(NULL, 0, bar);
         
         // Applica lo snap al prezzo più vicino
         clicked_price = GetNearestPrice(clicked_price, bar_open, bar_high, bar_low, bar_close);
         
         point_count++;
         
         switch(point_count)
         {
            case 1:
               time1 = bar_time; price1 = clicked_price;
               break;
            case 2:
               time2 = bar_time; price2 = clicked_price;
               break;
            case 3:
               time3 = bar_time; price3 = clicked_price;
               DrawPitchfork();
               drawing = false;
               break;
         }
      }
   }
   else if(id == CHARTEVENT_MOUSE_MOVE && drawing)
   {
      datetime cursor_time;
      double cursor_price;
      int window;
      
      if(ChartXYToTimePrice(0, (int)lparam, (int)dparam, window, cursor_time, cursor_price))
      {
         int bar = iBarShift(NULL, 0, cursor_time);
         datetime bar_time = iTime(NULL, 0, bar);
         double bar_open = iOpen(NULL, 0, bar);
         double bar_high = iHigh(NULL, 0, bar);
         double bar_low = iLow(NULL, 0, bar);
         double bar_close = iClose(NULL, 0, bar);
         
         // Applica lo snap al prezzo più vicino
         cursor_price = GetNearestPrice(cursor_price, bar_open, bar_high, bar_low, bar_close);
         
         ObjectDelete(0, cursor_line);
         ObjectCreate(0, cursor_line, OBJ_TREND, 0, bar_time, 0, bar_time, ChartGetDouble(0, CHART_PRICE_MAX));
         ObjectSetInteger(0, cursor_line, OBJPROP_COLOR, InpCursorColor);
         ObjectSetInteger(0, cursor_line, OBJPROP_STYLE, STYLE_DOT);
         
         ObjectDelete(0, price_text);
         ObjectCreate(0, price_text, OBJ_TEXT, 0, bar_time, cursor_price);
         ObjectSetString(0, price_text, OBJPROP_TEXT, DoubleToString(cursor_price, _Digits));
         ObjectSetInteger(0, price_text, OBJPROP_COLOR, InpCursorColor);
         
         ObjectDelete(0, time_text);
         ObjectCreate(0, time_text, OBJ_TEXT, 0, bar_time, 0);
         ObjectSetString(0, time_text, OBJPROP_TEXT, TimeToString(bar_time));
         ObjectSetInteger(0, time_text, OBJPROP_COLOR, InpCursorColor);
         
         ChartRedraw();
      }
   }
}

double GetNearestPrice(double price, double bar_open, double bar_high, double bar_low, double bar_close)
{
   // Calcolo dinamico dei prezzi senza array statici
   double nearest_price = price;
   double min_distance = DBL_MAX;
   
   // Controlla bar_open
   double distance = MathAbs(price - bar_open);
   if (distance <= InpProximity && distance < min_distance)
   {
      min_distance = distance;
      nearest_price = bar_open;
   }
   
   // Controlla bar_high
   distance = MathAbs(price - bar_high);
   if (distance <= InpProximity && distance < min_distance)
   {
      min_distance = distance;
      nearest_price = bar_high;
   }
   
   // Controlla bar_low
   distance = MathAbs(price - bar_low);
   if (distance <= InpProximity && distance < min_distance)
   {
      min_distance = distance;
      nearest_price = bar_low;
   }
   
   // Controlla bar_close
   distance = MathAbs(price - bar_close);
   if (distance <= InpProximity && distance < min_distance)
   {
      min_distance = distance;
      nearest_price = bar_close;
   }
   
   return nearest_price;
}

void DrawPitchfork()
{
   if(ObjectFind(0, pitchfork_name) != -1)
      ObjectDelete(0, pitchfork_name);
   
   ObjectCreate(0, pitchfork_name, OBJ_PITCHFORK, 0, time1, price1, time2, price2, time3, price3);
   
   ObjectSetInteger(0, pitchfork_name, OBJPROP_COLOR, InpMiddleColor); // Linea centrale
   ObjectSetInteger(0, pitchfork_name, OBJPROP_LEVELCOLOR, 1, InpUpperColor); // Primo livello (superiore)
   ObjectSetInteger(0, pitchfork_name, OBJPROP_LEVELCOLOR, 2, InpLowerColor); // Secondo livello (inferiore)
   ObjectSetInteger(0, pitchfork_name, OBJPROP_STYLE, InpLineStyle);
   ObjectSetInteger(0, pitchfork_name, OBJPROP_WIDTH, InpLineWidth);
   ObjectSetInteger(0, pitchfork_name, OBJPROP_SELECTABLE, true);
   
   ObjectSetInteger(0, pitchfork_name, OBJPROP_LEVELWIDTH, 1, InpLineWidth); // Primo livello
   ObjectSetInteger(0, pitchfork_name, OBJPROP_LEVELWIDTH, 2, InpLineWidth); // Secondo livello
   ObjectSetInteger(0, pitchfork_name, OBJPROP_LEVELS, 2);
   
   ObjectDelete(0, cursor_line);
   ObjectDelete(0, price_text);
   ObjectDelete(0, time_text);
   
   ChartRedraw();
}

void OnTimer()
{
   if(drawing)
   {
      string message = "Seleziona il punto " + IntegerToString(point_count + 1) + " del Pitchfork";
      Comment(message);
   }
   else
   {
      Comment("Pitchfork completato. Modifica i punti negli input per aggiustare.");
   }
}



Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].
